# Reading a file from a user input

Tags: java, file

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new File("postfix.txt"));
    while (myfile.hasNext()) {
        input = myfile.nextLine();
        inputArray = input.split(" ");
        if (inputArray.length == 3) {
            inputArray = input.split(" ");
            Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
            Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
            String operator = inputArray[2];
            try {
                switch (operator) {
                case "+":
                    result = number1 + number2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    result = number1 - number2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    result = number1 / number2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    result = number1 * number2;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Received unsupported operator: "
                            + operator);
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Your expression is:" + number1
                        + operator + number2);
                System.out.println("Your answer is: " + result);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid expression");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Your file is not found: -" + e.getMessage());
}
```

the text would be like this

```
44 3 +
9.99 + 0.09
12 0 *
. 10 -
10.2 2 *
12 4 /
66.1 0.12 -
.0 99.10 +
300 4.0 +
* 20 10 /
10 20
5.2 +
1 2 &
100 139 -
- 80 2
9 5 2
4 / 3
3 A -
200.5 10 *
2 * 4
8 2 *
10 20 -
8 16 /
-4 12 +
+ 4 2
x y z
```

The expression:

```
Please enter your file name:
```

All the above expressions should be resolved however the ones that are like:
`x y z, + 4 2` should come up with invalid expression.

When I run my code, only one expression in the text is resolved. After that, it comes up with invalid expression but doesn't carry on reading the text. Also, it needs to ask the user to type in there file name and read from that, but at the moment it only reads from the file that is already on the system.

Comment: Hey Computing, have you got a good answer?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in second line of your file since you are asking 
double double operator and you have there double operator double

9.99 + 0.09

to prevent stopping the program surround the parsing with try chatch

Set the

```
try{...
```

before parsing

For reading the file name from console

```
Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your file name: ");
        String path = lineScanner.nextLine();
        Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new File(path));....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this,

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new File("postfix.txt"));
        while (myfile.hasNext()) {
            String input = myfile.nextLine();
            inputArray = input.split(" ");
            if (inputArray.length == 3) {
                inputArray = input.split(" ");

                String operator = null;
                Double number1 = null;
                Double number2 = null;
                try {
                    number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
                    number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
                    operator = inputArray[2];
                } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    switch (operator) {
                        case "+":
                            result = number1 + number2;
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            result = number1 - number2;
                            break;
                        case "/":
                            result = number1 / number2;
                            break;
                        case "*":
                            result = number1 * number2;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Received unsupported operator: "
                                    + operator);
                            break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Your expression is:" + number1
                            + operator + number2);
                    System.out.println("Your answer is: " + result);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid expression");

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Your file is not found: -" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I am sure something is still missing because I couldn't understand your problem completely.

**Clear explain the condition you want to get.**

*Till then use the above code.*

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your try and catch block for `NumberFormatException` are NOT wrapping the correct block of code that parses string to double.

Move the `try {`

```
try {
   switch (operator) {
```

To

```
try {
   Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
```

to guard the correct block of code.

Comment: @computing glad it helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your problem:)